# does autocommit slow down performance in python?

Tags: python, mysql, commit

I've been working with Python MySQLdb. With InnoDB tables `autocommit` is turned off in default and that was what I needed. But since I'm now working with MyISAM tables, the docs for MySQL say

> MyISAM tables effectively always operate in autocommit = 1 mode

Since I'm running up to a few hundreds of queries a second, does committing with every single query slow down the performance of my script? Because I used to commit once every 1000 queries before, now I can't do that with MyISAM. If it slows it down, what can I try?

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM has no transactions, so you can't not to "autocommit" using MyISAM.
Your runtime change may be also caused by the fact you moved from innoDB to MyISAM.

The best approach for DB runtime issues in general is benchmarking, benchmarking and benchmarking.